# copying an object value from a form and pasting it to a table

Tags: sql, vba

I am new to using VBA and am studying heavily to try to get up to speed and become an advanced MS Access database programmer.   Although I understand many things, it seems to me that some of the basics I still have not got a full grasp.  My question which will be a big help with a database i am currently designing for a team at work involves capturing a value from an object and importing it (copying it) to a table.  Basically, in short, i need to know what commands in VBA will allow me to have one (or more) fields from the current record of a form inserted into a table. I would like to do this without having to build a field to 1-select the record and 2-launch a copy paste string.

After a lot of research i did find someone who gave me the means to write the code below and it works quite successfully.. ONly that, it is not VBA and i am wondering if there is a better, VBA based way to write it. I am getting confused with all the languages which I am coming accross while tyring to get up to speed

I hope to hear soon from someone.
Andrew

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblHoldingProjectID", dbOpenTable)
rst.AddNew
rst!ID_Project = Me.txtProjectNumber
rst.Update
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

note- 'txtProjectNumber' is the object name i gave to an expression i created on a form to identify the ID record number of the record currently selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the question, but:
To reference objects in the form, you can use their names (as you did with txtProjectNumber). To write records to a database, you cannot use "just VBA", but you need to user either DAO or ADODB library (DAO in your code above) which is an interface to a database (I assume there is also some code before the bit above to open CurrentDb).

Then you can reference to the fields in a table opened (your rst object) by either

`rst!*FieldName=`

or

`rst.Fields("FieldName").Value=` or `rst.Fileds(ID).Value=`

where IDs start go from 0 to rst.Fields.Count - 1.

If you have some sort of mapping defind somewhere or your controls and database fields have the same names, you can do some loops such as:

```
Dim c as Control
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
' do your DB open procedure + open rst'
rst.AddNew
For Each c in Me.Controls
  rs.Fields(c.Name).Value = c.Value
Next c
rst.Update
rst.Close
```

You can add some If conditions inside your loop to determine which fields should be staored etc.

Comment: ex-man..   Fantastic..  Thank you very much..  I am having a lot of fun Learning on my own but without people like you I would be way behind...